# First contact related to an account should be automatically marked as primary and with addition of next Contact the checkbox should be empty

Tags: apex

Please help me to resolve my issue. I've created a trigger handler that marks the Primary_Contact__c checkbox when inserting a new Contact on the Account without contacts. But when I try to create another Contact it continues to mark it as Primary.

```
public with sharing class PrimaryContactOnAccount {
public static void createFirstContactAsPrimaryContact(List<Contact> newContacts) {
    List<Account> accountsWithoutContacts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)];

    for (Contact con : newContacts) {
        for (Account act : accountsWithoutContacts) {
            con.Primary_Contact__c = true;


                }
            }
        }
```

here is the Trigger for it:

```
 trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after update,before insert, before update){
        if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
            PrimaryContactOnAccount.createFirstContactAsPrimaryContact(Trigger.new);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying for every account in the database, not just the contacts in your trigger. Instead, you need to be more selective, and bulkify your code. This follows the extremely common [aggregate-query-update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) that you'll use in pretty much every trigger you ever write.

Here's what that looks like:

```
public class PrimaryContactOnAccount {
    public static void createFirstPrimaryContactAsPrimaryContact(Contact[] records) {
        // New Account Ids, Account Ids already marked with a primary contact
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>(), existingIds = new Set<Id>();
        // Get account ids
        for(Contact record: records) {
            accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
        }
        // Get all account Ids that have a primary contact
        existingIds.addAll(new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT AccountId Id
            FROM Contact
            WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds AND Primary_Contact__c = TRUE
            GROUP BY AccountId
        ]).keySet());
        for(Contact record: records) {
            // If existingIds.add() returns true, there was no previous primary contact
            record.Primary_Contact__c = existingIds.add(record.AccountId);
        }
    }
}
```